# Model creation failing with has_many through validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I have 2 models, `order` and `owner`, which are joined together by an `order_owner` model using a `has_many through` association. Each `order` must have at least 1 `owner` associated to it but since each `order` or `owner` can have many of the other, a many-to-many relationship is required.

I've set up my `order` model with `validates :owners, presence: true` which works great if I attempt to create an `order` without associating any `owners` to it. However, the issue I'm encountering is that the validation still fails regardless of associating an `owner` at the time of creation via nested attributes and I don't know how to fix it.

**Models** - Rails 5.0.2

```
##order.rb
has_many :order_owners, inverse_of: :order, dependent: :destroy
has_many :owners, through: :order_owners

accepts_nested_attributes_for :owners, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_owners, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

validates :owners, presence: true

##owner.rb
has_many :order_owners, inverse_of: :owner, dependent: :destroy
has_many :orders, through: :order_owners

##order_owner.rb
belongs_to :owner
belongs_to :order

accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
```

I've tried using custom validation methods like

```
validate :must_have_owner
...
def must_have_owner
  if owners.empty? or owners.all? { |owner| owner.marked_for_destruction? }
    errors.add(:base, 'Order must have at least one owner')
  end
end
```

But the same thing occurs.

The way that I'm associating `owners` to an `order` upon creation is via nested attributes and using the `Cocoon gem`. So a user fills out the `order` form, then adds the appropriate `owners` (either via a `Owners.all` select or adding a new `owner` to be created), then submits the form. Without the aforementioned validation the whole process works fine but it also allows an `order` to be created without an `owner` which defeats the purpose.

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: If you place a breakpoint (with `byebug`) in your custom validate method, you will be able to see the state of the `Order` being constructed. I think your issue is that `order.order_owners` is present but `order.owners` is empty (because the new `order_owners` are not persisted yet and initialization a join record does make the object accessible via getters for the "being built" object).

Comment: @MrYoshiji Ah interesting approach, you’re probably right then. And initializing a join record in the sense of something like order.build_owners?

Comment: In the sense that if you do `order = Order.new ; order.order_owners.new`, then `order.order_owners.size` is `1` but `order.owners` is still `0`

Comment: Okay I just tried that in the console and that's exactly what happens. What would be the best approach to resolve that? If you formulate it into a working answer then I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: would: `validates :order_owners, presence: true, on: create` work for now? After all you've got a `validates :owner_id, presence: true` on your join model yes?

Comment: Oh yeah I guess that does work, so that resolves the creation issue at the moment but then I assume I'll need to do something along the lines of `validates :owners, presence: true, on: :update` for after that. This doesn't seem like the cleanest way to resolve it but it is working so thank you! And I have `validates :owner, presence: true` on my join model, would it better to have it validating `:owner_id` instead or are they effectively the same thing?

Comment: dont use `validates :owner_id`, because you are using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner`, so if you are building a new `owner` the validation will fail (because `owner_id` is null since the owner is not persisted yet)